# Javascript requestAnimationFrame spinner

Tags: javascript, animation

After investigating all possible ways to create a lightweight and flexible spinner, I ended up using `requestAnimationFrame` which is quite brilliant. It basically does the same thing as CSS3 `animation`: perform calculations and hand the result off to the browser in order to sync repaint with screen redraw (typically at 60fps). While CSS3 `transition` and `animation` are suitable for very basic usage since there's only a `transitionend` event which may not fire under certain circumstances, `requestAnimationFrame` offers full control and you can perform multiple complex calculations perfectly in sync with screen redraw.

Would it make sense to excecute this code in a HTML5 worker ?

**CSS**

```
i.spinner {position:relative;display:inline-block;margin:20px}
i.bar {display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;height:inherit}
i.bar i {display:block;width:100%;height:29%;background:#000}
i.bar:nth-child(2) {transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(45deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(3) {transform:rotate(90deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(90deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(4) {transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(135deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(135deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(135deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(5) {transform:rotate(180deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(180deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(180deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(6) {transform:rotate(225deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(225deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(225deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(225deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(7) {transform:rotate(270deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(270deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(270deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(270deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(8) {transform:rotate(315deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(315deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(315deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(315deg)}
```

**JS**

```
function buildspinner(size, invert) {
  var color = '#000',
    spinner = document.createElement('i'),
    bar = document.createElement('i'),
    hand = document.createElement('i'),
    opacitymap = [0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
    nodemap = [];
  if (invert) {color = '#fff'};
  spinner.className = 'spinner';
  spinner.style.cssText = 'width:' + size + 'px;height:' + size + 'px';
  bar.className = 'bar';
  bar.style.cssText = 'width:' + (size / 9) + 'px;height:' + size + 'px;margin-left:' + (-size / 18) + 'px';
  hand.style.cssText = 'border-radius:' + size + 'px;background:' + color;
  bar.appendChild(hand);
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var clone = bar.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.opacity = opacitymap[j];
    spinner.appendChild(clone);
    nodemap.push(clone)
  }
  document.body.appendChild(spinner);
  requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(timestamp, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, 0)})
}

function animatespinner(starttime, timestamp, duration, opacitymap, nodemap, counter) {
  var progress = (timestamp - starttime) / duration;
  counter++;
  if (counter % 3 == 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      var next = j - 1;
      if (next < 0) {
        next = 7
      };
      nodemap[j].style.opacity = (opacitymap[j] + (opacitymap[next] - opacitymap[j]) * progress)
    }
  }
  if (progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(starttime, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, counter)})
  } else {
    var rotatearray = opacitymap.pop();
    opacitymap.unshift(rotatearray);
    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(timestamp, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, 0)})
  }
}
```

The `counter` variable is used for throttling. You want the animation to be smooth, but you want to keep CPU usage low. In this example we change opacity every 3 frames instead of every frame, heavily reducing CPU overhead wihtout noticeable effect on smoothness. (CPU usage was reduced from 12% to 5% on a Quadcore 3GHz processor).

Because CSS3 `animation` relies on `keyframes` you would have to create a separate keyframe for each spinner hand, resulting in way too much calculations. The same spinner built with CSS3 animation resulted in 30% CPU usage.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdJmQZ?editors=011)

Comment: What exactly would you do in the worker and what in the main app? Are you considering the speed of the data going back and forth? Maybe you could test it, measure the performance and let us know.

Comment: @Shomz: I'm not familiar with workers, hence my question. A spinner is basically a repeating process, so I was wondering about CPU usage in case the spinner is run in a separate thread ?

Comment: Hmm, a web worked would be good to lift off some heavy calculations and then pass the results to the main app. And since most of your code is manipulating the DOM, I don't see any benefits from using a web worker... But let's see if somebody gives you a better answer.

Comment: I agree, it's mostly DOM manipulation and the screen redraw happens at 60fps so it makes sense not to put it in a worker. But on the other hand spinners are used to inform users there's something going on (like xhr callbacks) and they should hold on.

Comment: Yeah, they should definitely stay. Have you considered recreating it using the canvas technology?

Comment: I'm afraid not... Could you hilite the benefits of using canvas tech ?

Comment: It will save you from using multiple DOM elements (using only one instead) and can give you identical results... *probably* with a better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `requestAnimationFrame` is that it's efficiently called by the browser at as close to 60fps as possible, or whatever the frame-rate of the browser's animation engine is, and therefore you shouldn't be doing work in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback that would take longer than a frame-time.  Keep in mind that in a browser, the execution of javascript happens very fast ... it takes a very complex amount of javascript calculations to actually take longer than a frame-time to execute.  The main issues you'll run into are layout, painting, and redrawing elements on the screen.  And for that, a web-worker isn't going to help you.  A web-worker is only going to help you if you had really heavy javascript that would take longer than a frame-time to execute.

This is fairly easy to profile too ... You can look in Chrome's timeline tool to see how long your javascript function is taking to execute.  Chances are it's on the order of only 1ms max, and if your animation is running at less than 60fps, it's because layout and repainting are taking longer than the remaining 16.7ms in the frame-time, but that's in the browser layout engine itself, and not something you can offload via a webworker anyways.

Comment: Tested in Chrome: fps=60, js excecution average=0.214msec

Answer (score 2):

This code shows how long the browser takes just to send and receive a message to a worker. In my machine it takes about 3ms. You need to keep each frame of your JS under 10ms if you want to achieve 60fps (remember the browser still needs to style, layout, paint and composite each frame).

```js
var myWorker, 
    send = document.querySelector('.send'),
    receive = document.querySelector('.receive'),
    time = document.querySelector('.time'),
    start, end;

var sendMessage = function () {
  start = performance.now();  
  myWorker.postMessage('My message');
  console.log('Sending message to worker ' + start);
};

var receiveMessage = function(event) {
  end = performance.now();
  time.textContent = (end - start) + 'ms';
  receive.textContent = event.data; 
  console.log('Message received from worker ' + end);
};

var workerFunction = function(event) { 
  self.postMessage('Worker response: ' + event.data); 
};

var createWorker = function () {
  if (window.Worker && window.Blob && window.URL) {
    var workerContent = "self.onmessage = " + workerFunction.toString();
    var blob = new Blob([workerContent], {type: 'application/javascript'}); 
    myWorker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    myWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
  }
};

createWorker();

send.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
```

```html
<button class="send">Send</button>
<p class="receive"></p>
<p class="time"></p>
```

Comment: Indeed, passing code to/from a worker takes more than 1msec, while the non-worker example takes 0.214msec on average to execute.